# What operations does the bigquery.readonly scope allow?

Tags: google-bigquery

The only documentation I can find on the scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly

is the exceedingly unhelpful brief blurb [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#gettingstarted) which says "View Data in Bigquery." And I've searched high and low.

What operations does this correspond to? Can the user start asynchronous jobs? Can they fetch completed jobs? Can they run synchronous jobs? With or without destination tables? I'm looking for a scope that only allows running tabledata.list(), or fetching completed results of asynchronous jobs (i.e. does not allow the user to start queries but does allow them to get data of queries that have been run)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operations that are allowed with a read-only scope:

- projects.list
- datasets.get
- datasets.list
- tables.get
- tables.list
- tabledata.list
- jobs.get
- jobs.list
- jobs.query
- jobs.getQueryResults

This is from looking at the code, so the list should be canonical. So in answer to your questions:

- Can the user start asynchronous jobs? Only jobs.query(), which does start an asynchronous job under the covers. (it often returns synchronously, but when it times out, you can get the results with jobs.getQueryResults().
- Can they fetch completed jobs? Yes ... either with jobs.get() or jobs.getQueryResults()
- Can they run synchronous jobs? Only via jobs.query().
- With or without destination tables? jobs.query() does not support specifying a destination table, so no, destination tables are not supported with the read-only scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Is there a way to restrict a user to reading data via tabledata.list(), so they can't start queries?

Comment: In order to start a query, the user needs to have READ access on a project. So you could give them read access on the dataset the table is in, but not make them a member of the project. Then they won't be able to run queries (you could have a separate project that you use for this case).

Comment: Great! Thanks for your fast response, I'm assuming it works similarly for streaming inserts with the bigquery.insertdata scope? (i.e. users can stream data in but cannot query). It was unclear from documentation that you must have a project role in order to start jobs (although it was clear that this was *sufficient* to start jobs, it wasn't clear that it was *necessary*). I'm still not exactly clear on what permissions are delegated to Project Roles, and what permissions are delegated to Dataset ACL. Can users with WRITE access but without a project role create tables for example?

Comment: Yes, bigquery.insertdata is sufficient to append to tables but not query. Users with write access but without a project role _can_ create tables, but they cannot run jobs that do so (load, copy, query, etc).

Comment: @JordanTigani Please, update the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) and API metadata (API Playground doesn't know about this scope - http://awesomescreenshot.com/03347zefd9) with the relevant info.

Comment: @JordanTigani [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/discovery/v1/discovery.apis.getRest?api=bigquery&version=v2&fields=auth&_h=3&) shows that auth object is missing read-only scope: `{
 "auth": {
  "oauth2": {
   "scopes": {
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"
  }}}}`

Comment: @JordanTigani, I am granting read_only scope authorization (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly) from FE js side and obtaining the refresh token. In BE, with BigQuery Java API, I run 'bigQuery.query(queryConfig)' but not able to run any query (select query). The error says "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.", PERMISSION_DENIED. But, when I grant 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery' no issues, I can run queries

Comment: @JordanTigani in Java API, BigQueryOptions have a hardcoded scope as 'googleapis.com/auth/bigquery' so it is unable to overwrite. Thus, when I get the read_only scope, it sends requests with read/write scope and got permission denied I guess